# Horizontal distribution on $S^3 \to S^2$ and non torsion free connections

Tags: riemannian-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections, hopf-fibration

Thanks in advance to everyone! I am a little bit confused regarding connection on principal bundles. I explain my problem.
Consider $S^2$ with the standard metric and the Levi Civita connection and the hopf bundle $S^3 \to S^2$. I can consider an
horizontal distribution on $S^3$ that induced the same (standard) covariant derivative and parallel transport on $S^2$. What I’m trying to do now is the following. I have a different metric on $S^2$ and a connection that is compatible with that metric, but not torsion free. I would like to find the horizontal distribution on $S^3$ that induce the same connection on the base space. How should I do? I tried to use the Cartan equations with torsion, but I’m not sure the result is correct!

Thank you!

Comment: You should include the work you have done so far.